# Git aliases with long options not working

Tags: macos, git, alias

I have a .gitconfig file with some aliases in. The two aliases I have with long options don't work. I have this:

```
[alias]
    cam = "commit -am"
    cm = "commit -m"
    co = "checkout"
    last = "log -1 HEAD"
    log = 'log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all'
    rm = "rm --cached"
    st = "status"
```

Each alias works apart from `log` and `rm` which run the git command without the long option (i.e. `git rm` runs `git rm` and not `git rm --cached`).

I'm running homebrew-installed Git 2.3.2 on OSX 10.10.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Long options" have nothing to do with this. Those two aliases of yours do not work as expected because `log` and `rm` are built-in Git verbs and, as stated in the [`git-config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config),

> To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing Git commands are ignored.

Simply use different alias names, such as `logg` and `rmc`.